# Sort lists by items at given index

Tags: python, arrays

Sorry if I get terminology wrong - I've only just started learning Python, and I'm receiving instruction from friends instead of being on an actual course.

I want to search a list containing lots of arrays containing multiple elements, and find arrays with some elements matching, but some different.

In less confusing terms e.g. I have a list of arrays that each contain 2 elements (I think this is called a 2D array?) so:

```
list = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 5], [4, 1], [5, 2], ...]
```

In my specific example, the first elements in each sub array just ascend linearly, but the second elements are almost random. I want to find or sort the arrays only by the second number. I could just remove the first number from each array:

```
list = [2, 2, 5, 1, 2 ...]
```

And then use something like "if list[x] == 1" to find '1' etc.
(side note: I'm not sure how to find ALL the values if one value is repeated - I can't remember quite what I wrote but it would only ever find the first instance where the value matched, so e.g. it would detect the first '2' but not the second or third)

But I want to keep the first values in each array. My friend told me that you could use a dictionary with values and keys, which would work for my example, but I want to know what the more general method would be.

So in my example, I hoped that if I wrote this:

```
if list[[?, x]] == [?, 1]
```

Then it would find the array where the second value of the array was 1, (i.e. [4, 1] in my example) and not care about the first value. Obviously it didn't work because '?' isn't Python syntax as far as I'm aware, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do?

So for a more general case, if I had a list of 5 dimensional arrays and I wanted to find the second and fourth values of each array, I would write:

```
if list[[?, x, ?, y, ?]] == [?, a, ?, b, ?]
```

And it would match any array where the value of the second element was 'a', and the value of the fourth was 'b'.

e.g. [3, a, 4, b, 7], [20, a, 1, b, 9], ['cat', a, 'dog', b, 'fish'] etc. would all be possible results found by the command.

So I want to know if there's any similar way to my method of using a question mark (but that actually works) to denote that an element in an array can have any value.

Comment: What do you mean by "array": a Python `array.array`, a Python `list` or a `numpy.ndarray`?

Comment: "I think this is called a 2D array?" Here, I would call it a list of lists. Use `numpy` if you want more proper 2D arrays.

Comment: And another command: *never* use built-in keywords for variables names (i.e., don't use `list` as a variable here).

Comment: Edit: pressing 'enter'/'shift+enter' for line breaks in my comment doesn't seem to work, sorry if it reads confusingly.

@Evert I don't understand what is meant by 'numpy', and I'm not sure what you mean by "don't use 'list' as a variable" - in my program I used names like 'randlist' (short for 'random list') - is that better?

> What do I mean by "array"

I'm probably incorrect to assume this but I was using "array" and "list" interchangeably - I thought an array was just a specific type of list. So yes, when I said "array of arrays" I thought it was synonymous with "list of lists".

Comment: On using `list` as a variable: you can convert things to a list using the built-in function `list`, like `list("asdf")` (convert a string to a list of characters). But: `list = [1,2,3]; list("asdf")` results in an error, because you've assigned the built-in `list` function to something else.

Comment: [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/): a Python library for fast calculations with arrays of (numerical) data.

Comment: Btw, for questions on learning Python, there's a [special mailing list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out the mailing list. BTW If I use list("asdf"), how do then access the result / what is the list containing [a,s,d,f] called? I tried googling it but I can't find information on the list function - only general info about lists.

Comment: "how do then access the result": you assign it to a variable: `a = list("asdf")`. And the resulting list (stored in variable `a`) is simply called a list (specifically, a list of characters). Seen the question and (imo obvious) answer, you may have meant to ask something else. Don't bother too much about it: the example was mostly to indicate that if you use a builtin Python function name as a variable name  (`list`, `set`, `bin` are some classic examples), you may end up in trouble, so try and avoid that.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I did actually mean that but I figured it out for myself pretty quickly... I started messing around with it and after a few hours I managed to create a really complex (for how long I've actually been trying this programming stuff) program and I'm super pleased with myself... :D

Answer (score 2):

To sort on the second element for a list containg lists (or tuples):

```
from operator import itemgetter
mylist = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 5], [4, 1], [5, 2]]
sortedlist = sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(1))
```

See the [Python sorting howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly does this do/how do you use this function?

Also I'd prefer to use more 'basic' steps instead of more powerful functions - I managed to solve my friend's challenge (which was 'find the mode of a random list') just by searching for a 'mode' function, and my entire program was only 3 lines long, but I wanted to try it using only the simpler functions my friend had shown me (for loops, if statements etc.)...

Comment: Simple written-out functions are fine for learning algorithms, but if you want to learn Python and programming, keeping things short and comprehensible probably fits better. Sometimes, one sentence translates straight into one line of Python code: "find the mode of a random list" -> `scipy.stats.mstats.mode(data)`. So the answer here depends on your learning context: StackOverflow is for practical answers to actual problems, while for example [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) may help you with questions on algorithms.

Comment: I dunno, I want to learn programming but when I write something, I want to know how it works. My dad is also a programmer and told me once about how it works all the way down to binary/machine code - I guess I don't want to go quite that far down but it feels almost like cheating to plug in a function which is an entire program in itself, without working out what the function actually does. I guess I understood my friend's challenge as "Write a program to find the mode of a list", so just using a mode function wouldn't be writing my own program, it'd just be using someone else's prewritten one

Comment: If you have the time: do both. Write it in for-loops and if-else statements to learn the algorithm, then find a Pythonic way to do it in (sometimes) one-line and learn Python. [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) will be a good place to find out how to simplify/"readabilify" your code. (Note: almost never implement your own algorithm when there's an existing one. Most existing ones are faster and more foolproof.)

Comment: Yes! This is pretty much what I want to do - I'll use a powerful function only once I've learned how it works/built it myself in smaller logical terms, but then once I've 'earned' its usage I'll use it without having to think through how it works again. Going back to the original question, though - I'm still not sure how to search for some elements in a sub-list but not others, and I don't want to use 'itemgetter' until I know what it does/how it works...

Comment: "I'm still not sure how to search for some elements in a sub-list but not others": I think the problem here is that you actually have multiple questions in your question. Focus on one issue, solve that (possibly using SO), then go to the next issue. If you had asked "Write a program to find the mode of a list", you would have gotten quite different answers again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` if you want to keep original `list` unaffected

```
lst = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 5], [4, 1], [5, 2]]
In [103]: sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[103]: [[4, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [5, 2], [3, 5]]
```

else use `list.sort` to sort current list and keep sorted list

```
In [106]: lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
In [107]: lst
Out[107]: [[4, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [5, 2], [3, 5]]
```

or use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
from operator import itemgetter
In [108]: sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(1))
Out[108]: [[4, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [5, 2], [3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a list of all the desired items:

```
In [16]: seq = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 5], [4, 1], [5, 2]]
```

To find all items where the second element is 1:

```
In [17]: [pair for pair in seq if pair[1] == 1]
Out[17]: [[4, 1]]
```

This finds all items where the second element is 2:

```
In [18]: [pair for pair in seq if pair[1] == 2]
Out[18]: [[1, 2], [2, 2], [5, 2]]
```

---

Instead of

```
if list[[?, x, ?, y, ?]] == [?, a, ?, b, ?]
```

you could use

```
[item for item in seq if item[1] == 'a' and item[3] == 'b']
```

---

Note, however, that each time you use a list comprehension, Python has to loop
through *all* the elements of `seq`. If you are doing this search multiple times, 
you might be better off building a dict:

```
import collections
seq = [[1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 5], [4, 1], [5, 2]]
dct = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in seq:
    key = item[1] 
    dct[key].append(item)
```

And then you could access the items like this:

```
In [22]: dct[1]
Out[22]: [[4, 1]]

In [23]: dct[2]
Out[23]: [[1, 2], [2, 2], [5, 2]]
```

---

The list comprehension

```
[pair for pair in seq if pair[1] == 1]
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
result = list()
for pair in seq:
    if pair[1] == 1:
        result.append(pair)
```

in the sense that `result` would then equal the list comprehension.

The list comprehension is just a syntactically prettier way to express the same
thing.

The list comprehension above has three parts:

```
[expression for-loop conditional]
```

The expression is `pair`, the for-loop is `for pair in seq`, and the conditional is `if pair[1] == 1`.

Most, [but not all](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) list comprehensions share this syntax. The full list comprehension grammar is [given here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 


Could you break down what "item for item in seq if item" means? (And what "pair for pair in seq if pair" means, if that's different?)

Yes, I mentioned that my friend had told me briefly about dictionaries, but from what I can tell, it looks like their use is limited to 2D lists and where one element is just increasing in value linearly - i.e. a 2D list where both variables are random in each sub-list wouldn't work because there could be multiple, or zero matches for a given key...

Comment: I've added an explanation of the list comprehension syntax. Be sure to read the links to the docs for a more complete explanation.